# POSIX message queues permission denied issue

Tags: unix, posix, ipc, message-queue

I have a `server.c` program that is initialising a message queue with the following permissions:

```
#define SERVER "/serverqueue"
...
struct mq_attr attr;
attr.mq_flags = 0;
attr.mq_maxmsg = MAX_MSGS;
attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_MSG_SIZE;
attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;
server = mq_open(SERVER, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 666, &attr)
...
```

In the first run, the `mq_open()` is successful and the program exits with no error. On subsequent executions, I get `Permission denied` errors at `mq_open()`. Why is this happening?
In case its relevant, I am not explicitly closing/unlinking the message queue descriptors as the OS does that automatically when the program exits, if i am not wrong

Comment: Hey guys, I am a newbie to `IPC`. It would be great if you could give me your two cents even if it's too trivial. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message queues persist after process exit.  The reason the second creation attempt fails is because you specify the mode as `666`, which results rather strange permissions:

```
$ ls -l /dev/mqueue/serverqueue
--w--wx--T. 1 fw fw 80 Feb 17 13:13 serverqueue
```

There are no read permissions, so opening with `O_RDWR` fails.

Furthermore, since the queue names are a shared resource, it usually results in a security vulnerability if you create queues with `O_CREAT` instead of `O_CREAT | O_EXCL`.  Another user could have created the same queue, with different permissions, and thus gain access to what you are trying to do with the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One clarification, I thought 666 meant read-write permissions to all processes. So why would `O_RDWR` fail?

Comment: Got it, it should be `0666`, my bad. I would rather prefer `0660`. Thanks for the clarification :)